# Lucene (6.2.1) deleteDocuments based on StoredField

Tags: search, indexing, lucene, full-text-search

I am using few `StoredField` and few `TextField` in my indexing (Lucene 6.2.1)

for every document I have my own unique ID

if I create field as

```
 Field docID = new TextField("docID", docId, Field.Store.YES);
```

I am able to delet document like following

```
Field transactionIdField = new TextField("transactionId", transactionId, Field.Store.YES);      
Term docIdTerm = new Term("docID", docId);
Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);
iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
IndexWriter writer = repositoryWriters.getTargetIndexWriter(repositoryUuid);

// 4. remove document with docId
writer.deleteDocuments(docIdTerm);
LOG.log(Level.INFO, "Document removed from Index, docID: {0}", docId);
writer.commit();
```

But if I create field as

```
 Field docID = new SttoredField("docID", docId);
```

the document is not deleted

How can I delete a document based on a Stored Field Value?

I want to keep it a StoredField so tat users can not search teh document based on docID

Answer (score 1):

Quoting `StoredField` documentation,

> A field whose value is stored so that IndexSearcher.doc and
>   IndexReader.document() will return the field and its value.

i.e. it would simply be a stored field for a document and there would be no Terms or Indexing for this field.

Method, `IndexWriter.deleteDocuments(Term...terms)` wouldn't find that document since there will be no Term for a `StoredField`.

A `TextField` on the other hand is indexed and terms generated for it,

> A field that is indexed and tokenized, without term vectors. For
>   example this would be used on a 'body' field, that contains the bulk
>   of a document's text.

A stored `TextField` is indexed as well as stored so terms are available and value is stored to re construct the document too.

So in sumamry, you can't delete a document on the basis of only a `StoredField` , you need an indexed field too - with same name to be able to delete it.